# How to find the limits or boundary of integration between two points?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Im trying to calculate the work done of a field between two points. The thing im struggling with is find the limits of integration. ie.
$$\int_a^b$$

Can anyone help, if the points were A(1,2) and B(3,4) what method would I use?

Comment: The limits are simply your points $A(1,2)$ and $B(3,4)$. You integrate along a curve from A to B. [Wikipedia has a nice animation to explain the concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field)

Comment: Do you know line integrals? The specific problem (i.e. with acting field written explicitely) would be good to see.

Comment: @ Wouter but once ive integrated, how can substitute in the point A(1,2) like it is a point of (x,y) do x get substituted into x and y into y ??

Comment: @Tomas I do but after i integrate can i substitute the points in, would i substitute the point A(1,2) into the equation after integration?

Comment: No it isn't like that. Your first step is to find a curve which connects the points $A$ and $B$ and then do a line integral over that curve with respect to the field. It really sounds like you need to look up what a line integral is. The link to in the first comment will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @BernardWojcik Ive done that! its easy to find an equation that links the two points and then ive done the line integral with respect to the field. Its just the limits that i dont know how to do

Comment: If you already have an equation for a curve that links the two points, say $x=x(t), y=y(t)$, then you have to integrate w.r.t. $t$, and the limits are simply the $t$ values for which $(x(t_0),y(t_0))=A$ and $(x(t_1),y(t_1))=B$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi:[a,b]\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ be some parametrisation of a curve $\Gamma$ with endpoints $\phi(a)=(1,2)=A$ and $\phi(b)=(3,4)=B$

To calculate the work done by the field $F$ as you move from $A$ to $B$ along $\Gamma$ you need to evaluate the line integral $\int_a^bF(\phi(t))\cdot \phi'(t) \,dt$

For example, you could choose your curve $\Gamma$ to be the line segment joining $A$ and $B$ and your parametrisation to be $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ given by $\phi(t)= (2t+1,2t+2)$ so the line integral would be $\int_0^1F(2t+1,2t+2)\cdot(2,2) \,dt$

Note that not only some fields (the conservative ones) will give you the same result for all curves.